# Sub-reports overlapping "Last Page Footer" band

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport, subreport

I have tried every combination of band configuration and layouts.

I have a master report and (currently) 2 *subreports*. The printout is a workorder and each work order must have X number of repair items and Y number of detailed parts used to repair the component. Sometimes there are only a few of each other times there are over 50 each.

Header of the report looks great. I have two bands where I place my *subreports*. Originally I had them both in the same band and specified the second *subreport* as "float" which resulted in the same effect as having each in separate bands.

The *subreports* display fine however on occasion the parts list will overlap the details I have specified in *Last Page Footer* band. This does not appear to happen when I place the labels in the *Summary* band however these labels are mostly boxes for signatures so alignment with the bottom of the page is required and summary seems to add labels and such at end of content.

Resizing the bands the *subreports* are in seems to work - kinda. However I need both *subreports* to start immediately after each other. So resizing bands isn't an option otherwise there is a bunch of white space between them and single page printing when only a few parts and repairs are selected does not happen.

Anyone have any ideas? Wisdom to share? Experience? This reminds me of working in HTML and sticky footers ugh :)

Comment: Are your subreports in detail bands?

Answer (score 2):

I know the question it's quite old, but since I had this problem and I already found the solution, I'll post it for someone that may need it in the future.

In my case, the problem was that I had the **Summary With page Header and Footer** checkbox selected. Once I put it to false, it worked like a charm.